# How does printf and scanf work in a loop? Why I dont need \n in scanf?

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, scanf, do-while

I dont really uderstand the code below. How does it work exactly (I/O buffers I mean). I dont need a `\n`character in my code an it still works! Can anyone explain it to me step by step?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = -1;

    do
    {
        printf("Give x: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }while(x<=0);

    printf("x = %d\n", x);

    x = -1;

    while(x<=0)
    {
        printf("Give x: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }

    printf("x = %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `\n` in `scanf`?

Comment: @haccks: because when I had `\n` in a `printf`, `printf("\nGive x: ");` I needed to add `puts("");` before the second `while` loop to get it work right

Comment: No. There is no need to put `puts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping away the parts OP likely understand, look at the `scanf()` calls.

The `"%d"` format specifier says to scan though optional whitespace (space, tab, \n, etc.) and then scan an `int`.  This typically continues until a character is encountered that does *not* belong to the `int`.  Then that character is "ungotten" (put back in the input buffer).

Say your input was `"  123  -456"`.  After the first while loop `"  -456"` would remain in the input buffer.  The second while loop would consume the `"  -456"`.  Assuming that `stdin` was closed after the `-456`, scanf() would then detect there is no more data and set `x` to the value -456.  As `x` is still negative, the second while loop performs `scanf()` again.  This time, no data and `scanf()` does not change `x` and returns EOF, which sadly is not monitored.  Result: endless loop.

Now try  `"  123a  456"`.  After the first while loop `"a  456"` would remain in the input buffer.  The second while loop would call `scanf()` and fail to convert anything as `a` does not begin a number - thus `x` remains -1.  `scanf()` would return 0, which unfortunately is not monitoring.  The `a`, not begin consumed, would remain in the input buffer.  The 2nd while loop again calls `scanf()` which would do the same thing resulting in an endless loop.

```
do {
  ...
  scanf("%d", &x);
} while (x<=0);
...
x = -1;
while (x<=0) {
  ...
  scanf("%d", &x);
}
```

Far better to use `fgets()/sscanf()` pair for input from user input.
(User input is *evil*!)

Answer (score 3):

According to [scanf's documentation on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

```
Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters
encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include
spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format
string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream 
including none).
```

This is why you don't need to specify the `\n` in `scanf` the next `scanf` call will simply ignore it.